# get Address Information in new order email

Tags: magento2.3, address

I need to display the Address information block in a new order email
[image]

Comment: you have to check this link `https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/190839/edit-billing-and-shipping-address-in-email-template`. Hope this one helps you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you editing the template in Admin?

This can help to render the addresses

```
  <table class="order-details">
                <tr>
                    <td class="address-details">
                        <h3>{{trans "Billing Address"}}</h3>
                        <p>{{var formattedBillingAddress|raw}}</p>
                    </td>
                    {{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}}
                    <td class="address-details">
                        <h3>{{trans "Shipping Address"}}</h3>
                        <p>{{var formattedShippingAddress|raw}}</p>
                    </td>
                    {{/depend}}
                </tr>
            </table>
```